# Can I use a PC Microphone in a PIC with ADC?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microphone, fft

I want to do an FFT on some music, I found an electret board so connect directly to the ADC port, but I was wondering if it's possible to use a normal computer microphone, anyone know a tutorial or something? or how to do it?

Comment: Microphone part number?

Comment: Computer microphones are in most cases also electret and need bias supply to power the internal preamplifier. A coupling capacitor to the ADC input is necessary.

Comment: Why not just use the microphone with a PC, and do the processing with existing software? Is there a reason to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because is a project for the school =P, so I have to design with a microcontroller and a FFT. Anyone know some tutorial about the connection?

Comment: What do you mean by a "normal computer microphone"?  Something that connects to a microphone input on the PC?  Or are you thinking of USB?  If the latter then sure, it can be done, you just need an MCU that is capable of acting as a USB host or OTG and ]the necessary specifications (and enough nous) to write a USB driver to suit that microphone and MCU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electret requires a biasing circuit, you cannot connect directly to the PIC. The signal would be very small so you'll need an instrumentation amplifier. The PIC ADC lacks the sensitivity for the raw signal (see #2 below).  You'll also run into trouble with aliasing so you'll need an analog low pass filter.

Some other things to consider:

1. The best sampling rate you can probably get is 10-12 kHz, which means you can only get up to 5-6 kHz due to Nyquist, which is not nearly enough for music.  Most hearing aids do 16 kHz, and that is for old people who are missing most of their high frequency hearing already.
2. The best resolution you can probably get is 10-12 bits.  Which means you will have a high noise floor, so only really loud sounds will make it through.  Or if you amplify a lot, loud sounds will saturate the input.
3. FFT is a demanding calculation, you would have to use an 8-point or 16-point FFT which probably isn't the resolution you were hoping for. Maybe their dsPIC33s can handle more, but streaming FFT calculations is out of the question for most of their PICs.

You need more beef, consider doing it with a Rasberry Pi or something with Linux and an audio jack.  Doing that in real time will be quite challenging in itself, without having the hardware limitations of a PIC.  Don't get me wrong.  I love PICs, but they just aren't suited for audio, let alone music.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Anything suitable for capturing audio signals (i.e. a microphone) should be sufficient for a FFT.

Here is a tutorial for using LabVIEW in Fourier Analysis: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4541/en

Comment: Not necessarily for use with a PIC, which might well require a preamp.

Answer (score 2):

of course you can. But there are little things to watch out for.

Always note the max ADC Input voltage. Exceeding that will damage the MCU. Also note that you cannot just directly connect the MIC to the ADC. Simply because the mic needs to be biased. Take the quiescent point of the MIC to somewhere like 2.5 volts and then try sampling from the ADC. This is because you get an AC wave off the mic. So biasing will make sure you get both bottom as well as the top half of what you speak. And! make sure you common all grounds.

Since you are a beginner, I recommend using something like Micro C. Dont be mislead. Its not a language. Just the name of the compiler. for your case its called Micro C for PIC. So yes!, its specifically for your application. I remember, thats how I started too!

Its not really a good C compiler but, It will get you started. You will also need to find your self a good debugger.

The nice thing with Micro C is that they have all libraries set up for you. You just need to go to the example (help menu) and start calling the functions off the library already integrated by default to the compiler. But beware, you wont learn much by using this way. But this will you get all ready to doing this the proper way, with an understanding.

FFT is not really a simple thing to do. So make sure you know all math behind the same. Otherwise you will be confused as to why you are doing certain things.